# python list comprehension get dictionary by key

Tags: python

Given the key 'joe' how can I extract the dictionary `{'joe': 60}` from `my_list`?

```
my_list = [{'joe': 60}, {'dave': 61}]
```

I'd like to avoid using a for loop

Comment: If there is only one of each dict, why not convert this whole list into a dictionary and then return `my_dict['joe']`

Comment: Why are you using a list of dictionaries (instead of a simple dictionary)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[dic for dic in my_list if 'joe' in dic]
```

or more generally,

```
def get_dicts(alist, key):
    return [dic for dic in alist if key in dic]

get_dicts(my_list, 'joe')
```

However, if your dictionaries have only one key and the key is unique to each dictionary, your data structure might not be optimal. You could have a single dictionary `dic = {'joe': 60, 'dave': 50}` and just get `dic[joe]`

Comment: It's not possible to traverse a list without some kind of a for loop.

Comment: exactly, i don't think you can search through the list without some kind of iteration

Answer (score 1):

A loop is unavoidable, but you can mask it pretty well:

```
import itertools
next(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: key in x, my_list))
```

This either emits the first matching dict or raises a `StopIteration` exception that you can check for. Or you could go for recursion:

```
def matches(key, lst):
    if not lst:
        return None
    if key in lst[0]:
        return lst[0]
    return matches(key, lst[1:])
```

which is still a for loop but tries hard not to look like one.